# Disable Minute slider from datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm using jquery Datetimepicker addon to pick date and time, but I need to disable minutes slider from it.

I've tried following code but it won't worked.

```
$(element).datetimepicker({
  dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
  timeFormat : 'HH',
  showMinute : false,
  showOn : 'focus'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the format in to

```
format: 'HH:00'
```

Comment: @Balan..u mean timeFormat : 'HH', to timeFormat :'HH:00'

Comment: @Balan..working fine..but it is showing minute slider, i don't want to display it..

Comment: @Ravi..if u hide the side u can't select hour as well .do u what only select date?

Comment: i need to select date along with time in hours.. so I want to hide minute slider from datepicker ui

Answer (score 0):

It should be `timeFormat: 'hh:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

I have did it using the below given way,

```
$('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:00'
});
```

Just add `timeFormat` and set the value.